# Content length overriden by browser

Tags: angular, typescript

[image: Content Length Mismatch Error]

I am making a put call to upload a file. I am setting the Content Range according to the API and the total number of bytes are not matching to the content length. If I set the content length myself, I am getting an error Refused to set unsafe header "Content-Length".

And finally the error I am getting for file upload is.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "invalidRequest",
    "message": "The Content-Range header length does not match the provided number of bytes."
  }
}
```

Content Length is accepted and the call is successful if I make the request via Postman but when I make the API call in a web application, I am running into this issue.
Any ideas to solve this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Random guess: are you sending a string, and counting characters instead of bytes to determine your `Content-Range`? If there are non-ASCII characters in there, then UTF-8 encoding will make your string take up more bytes than characters.

Comment: sending file via formData. but i am setting the content range from the file.size property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by reading the file as Array Buffer.